# Purchasing an Obfuscator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Why should I pay for an obfuscator if Visual Studio ships with a free version (Dotfuscator Community Edition)?

Comment: You can generalize this question to "why pay for X when there is a free version available by them/their competetors?"  The answer to this question is equal to the business model of that company.  Sometimes it has been thought through by the company, sometimes it has a good answer that makes business sense for you as the consumer.  Sometimes it doesn't.

It sounds like the answer you were seeking was for the question "what in the paid version of Dotfuscator is worth $x?"

Answer (score 5):

Because Dotfuscator Community Edition uses only the most basic Obfuscation techniques.

Obfuscation is not a be-all end-all solution. If people want your code, they'll get it one way or another. Obfuscation just makes it more difficult.

Just check out the Dotfuscator editions page to see which techniques get used by which versions (and believe me, the PRO and Suite make your code MUCH more difficult to reverse engineer than the Community Edition):

[Dotfuscator Editions](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/compare-editions)

Comment: It is too expensive for the initial commercialization of personal software.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried Dotfuscator Community Edition it worked fine except it did not include resource files.

Buying an obfuscator will give you access to support if you have any trouble with the obfuscating process.

As I wanted so save the approx. 1000 Euro too, I'm writing my own obfuscator that is in fact a c#-c# compiler.

Comment: Don't know what you're worth per hour, but I hope it's less than 1000 / (# of hours that task will take you). Don't forget opportunity cost, etc.

Comment: I'm a student right now, and I always wanted to write a compiler. Even got a very big book on writing compilers - but sadly I don't have the time at the moment, so my 'compiler' is just a bunch of regex.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you need from obfuscator software. If you only want to reduce the size of compiled project, or speed it a little bit, free version is good enouhgt. If you are looking for some sort of source code or resource protection, free version is almost useless.

As I don't know the price of a license (Dotfuscator has no public price list) I doubt it will be 1000 Euro like price for a single developer. Similar product, [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm), is around 200$ for a lifelong one developer license.